# Listview with listadapter highlight item

Tags: android, listview, highlight

I am using a ListView with the code below. Problem is when I click on a list item it is not highlighted. You see, I tried to use `arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` but this results in when I click on the item and don't let my finger up, nothing happens, when I click on the item and let my finger up, it is highlighted AND stays that highlighted.
How to make that when I let my finger up the  highlight is removed?
I don't know why this is not behaving like a simple listview.

```
 private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter { 
        private ArrayList mList; 
        private Context mContext;

        public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList list) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
            this.mList = list;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;

            try {
                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }

                final Object listItem = mList.get(position);
                if (listItem != null) {

                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(((HotOrNot) listItem).getName());
                    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            Toast.makeText(SQLView.this, "ID: " + ((HotOrNot) listItem).getID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(SQLView.this, "Name: " + ((HotOrNot) listItem).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(SQLView.this, "Descr: " + ((HotOrNot) listItem).getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                           // finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.i(Splash.ListAdapter.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this question - it describes the solution to what you need.  In short you need to use a selector for your list item background. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434317/listview-with-listadapter-highlight-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this xml file in your `drawable` folder and  in list_item set background in mainlayout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="#FFFFFF" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="#FF00FF" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="#FF00FF" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>

    </selector>
```

Comment: what i cant understand your comment

Comment: you cant understand my answer ....First copy my answer from <?xml ...</selecter> then right click on drawable folder and create xml file and give name list_bg and save in drawable folder(Dont in layout),Then paste,,,then in your layout list_item have Any layout and give android:background="@drawable/list_bg" then clean and build your project and Rerun